# Exception while referring to a bean from ServiceActivator

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am getting the below exception when I am trying to ref the bean from *ServiceActivator* in Spring Integration:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.shephertz.app42.paas.service.ChannelAdapterDemo.main(ChannelAdapterDemo.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.isCglibProxyClass(AopUtils.java:96)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.getTargetClass(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:365)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:38)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: a little bit more details about your spring-context file will be helpful to find the cause of the error.

Comment: Hi Bill, here is the link to spring-context file https://gist.github.com/NaveenGShephertz/5524483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NoSuchMethodException is thrown. That means that spring tries yo access a method internally that doesn't exist. Are you using the same spring version for all like libraries?

Comment: Hi Templar, Below is the list of spring jars & their versions.... could you please let me know are these versions compatible.            
- spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
- spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
- spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-integration-jms-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Thanks Templar..... Modifying the spring integration jars to 2.1.5 have worked for me.....   spring-integration-jms-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar to spring-integration-jms-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar & spring-integration-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar to spring-integration-core-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar